# playing audio files placed in li tag

Tags: html, html5-audio, tizen

i used audio tag among li tag to play different files . i cannot see the audio scroll bar for none of them . why is it so ? please help me out . here is the sample code i tried to run

```
 <ul>
            <li>Enduko Emo<audio id="18000">
        <source src="./musicfiles/01._Enduko_Emo.mp3">
            </audio>
            </li>

             <li>Ela Ela<audio id="18001">
        <source src="./musicfiles/02. Ela Ela.mp3">
            </audio>
           </li>


        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you testing this on? They don't all support MP3.

Comment: i'm playing them in my tizen mobile application. problem is that i'm able to see the audio scroll bar only for the last li tag element

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no  element in your source code. Please put below  element to your source code. And try it again.

```
<head>
    <script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw-libs.js"></script>
    <script src="tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw.js" data-framework-theme="tizen-white"></script>
</head>
```